# Where to call function Fill Chart Array to reduce loading time?

Tags: ios, charts, ios-charts, viewdidappear

I am using iOS-Charts and I have a ViewController where I call the function that fills the data for the chart.

Currently I call it in from ViewDidAppear, but it takes quite long to load. Where is the best place to call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put expensive loading code in `viewDidAppear` it won't run until your view controller is fully onscreen. If possible you probably want to do this in `viewDidLoad`, since this is called before your view controller is onscreen. It will also only be called once during the view controller's initial setup, while `viewDidAppear` can be called many times if you're navigating away from / back to this view controller.

**Response to Comment**

The problem is that you're doing expensive work on the main thread / queue. So the thread of execution gets to your `viewDidLoad` and then everything has to wait for your work to finish before your function can exit and your view controller can be presented. What you want to do if possible is to perform your work asynchronously, on a separate queue, and then update your screen on the main thread when the work is complete:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.userInitiated).async {
        let results = someExpensiveOperation()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            updateViewWithResults(results)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: made my day! thank you so much! it works, but isn't this a way to move the loading time from one place to another? In this way the transition from the previous screen takes longer now (4-5 seconds). Is this normal ?

Comment: response to your edit. Thanks a lot again.  I had that structure but in ViewDidAppear. If I put it in ViewDidLoad it also takes a while.  I guess is normal to wait 5 seconds to fill a chart ?